# Write XML with JSoup

Tags: java, xml, jsoup

I have parsed an xml file with JSoup and now I want to write the (modified) object to a new xml file.

The problem is that JSoup adds a bunch of meta head html data.

It should start like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE score-partwise PUBLIC "-//Recordare//DTD MusicXML 2.0 Partwise//EN" "http://www.musicxml.org/dtds/partwise.dtd">
<score-partwise>
  <identification>
    <encoding>
```

But it actually starts like this:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?--><!DOCTYPE score-partwise PUBLIC "-//Recordare//DTD MusicXML 2.0 Partwise//EN" "http://www.musicxml.org/dtds/partwise.dtd">
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <score-partwise> 
   <identification> 
    <encoding> 
     <software>
      MuseScore 1.3
     </software> 
     <encoding-date>
      2015-01-31
     </encoding-date> 
    </encoding> 
    <source>http://musescore.com/score/161981 
   </identification> 
   <defaults> 
    <scaling> 
     <millimeters>
      7.056
     </millimeters> 
     <tenths>
      40
     </tenths> 
    </scaling> 
    <page-layout> 
     <page-height>
      1683.67
     </page-height> 
     <page-width>
      1190.48
     </page-width>
```

I have loaded the file like this:

```
 if (doc.getElementsByTag("note").isEmpty()) {
        doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-16", filename);
        if (doc.getElementsByTag("note").isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Please check that your file is encoded in UTF-8 or UTF-16 and contains notes.");
        }
    }
```

And have tried writing it like this:

```
BufferedWriter htmlWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.xml"), "UTF-8"));
        htmlWriter.write(doc.outerHtml());
```

-> I have tried doc.html() and doc.toString() as well. Still the same output.

Any ideas? I just want it to be written the same way it was read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved it:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename) {
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return 0;
    }
};

  doc = Jsoup.parse(is, "UTF-8", "", Parser.xmlParser());


if (doc.getElementsByTag("note").isEmpty()) {
    doc = Jsoup.parse(is, "UTF-8", "", Parser.xmlParser());
    if (doc.getElementsByTag("note").isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Please check that your file is encoded in UTF-8 or UTF-16 and contains notes.");
    }
}
```